# Scala How to find Map Key contain some word

Tags: scala

need your help,
i'm just a newbie that come to Scala Programming.

i have some map like sample below

```
Map(Y1A0001_001 -> CU, Y1D0003 -> A011, Y1C0002 -> 20211030, Y1D0000 -> four, Y1D0002 -> Today only, Y1C0001 -> 123123, Y1B0003 -> 005, Y1D0001 -> CitizenID, Y1C0000 -> Customer)
Map(Y1A0001_001 -> CU, Y1D0003 -> A011, Y1C0002 -> 20210928, Y1D0000 -> five, Y1D0002 -> Today only, Y1C0001 -> 133213, Y1B0003 -> 006, Y1D0001 -> Drive License, Y1C0000 -> Director)
Map(Y1A0001_001 -> CU, Y1D0003 -> A011, Y1C0002 -> 20210927, Y1D0000 -> six, Y1D0002 -> Both, Y1C0001 -> 452234324, Y1B0003 -> 007, Y1D0001 -> CitizenID, Y1C0000 -> Messenger)
```

How can i find the key that contain suffix 001 and get the value too in Scala programming?

for example the key is Y1A0001_001 and value is "CU"

please forgive me if my question is not clear enough

Thank you before for your help

Comment: You want to use the [`collectFirst` method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#collectFirst[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]) - Although, note that what you will do is iterating the whole `Map` until finding the key you want, that is ok but is not the use case intended for `Maps`, you may just use a `List` _(or any other `Seq`)_ of pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
val map: Map[String, String] = ???

val result: Option[(String, String)] = map.find { case (k,v) => 
  k.endsWith("001")
}
```

See Scaladoc: [https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option%5BA%5D)